# Avoid getting banned on sites using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to download data from gsmarena. A sample code to download HTC one me spec is from the following site "http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_me-7275.php" as mentioned below:

The data on the website is classified in form of tables and table rows. 
The data is of the format:

```
table header > td[@class='ttl'] > td[@class='nfo']
```

Items.py file:

```
import scrapy

class gsmArenaDataItem(scrapy.Item):
    phoneName = scrapy.Field()
    phoneDetails = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Spider file:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Spider
from gsmarena_data.items import gsmArenaDataItem

class testSpider(Spider):
    name = "mobile_test"
    allowed_domains = ["gsmarena.com"]
    start_urls = ('http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_me-7275.php',)

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract whatever stuffs you want and yield items here
        hxs = Selector(response)
        phone = gsmArenaDataItem()
        tableRows = hxs.css("div#specs-list table")
        for tableRows in tableRows:
            phone['phoneName'] = tableRows.xpath(".//th/text()").extract()[0]
            for ttl in tableRows.xpath(".//td[@class='ttl']"):
                ttl_value = " ".join(ttl.xpath(".//text()").extract())
                nfo_value = " ".join(ttl.xpath("following-sibling::td[@class='nfo']//text()").extract())
                colonSign = ": "
                commaSign = ", "
                seq = [ttl_value, colonSign, nfo_value, commaSign]
                seq = seq.join(seq)
        phone['phoneDetails'] = seq
        yield phone
```

However, I'm getting banned as soon  as I try to even load the page in scrapy shell using:

```
"http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_me-7275.php"
```

I've even tried using DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3 in settings.py.

Kindly suggest how should I go about it.

Answer (score 6):

That's probably happening because of the Scrapy's User Agent. As you can see [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html), the `BOT_NAME` variable is used to compose the `USER_AGENT`. My guess is that the site you want to crawl is blocking that. I tried to look over their [robots.txt file](http://www.gsmarena.com/robots.txt) but got no clue from there.

You can try to set up a custom UserAgent. In your `settings.py` add the following line:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
```

Actually, your `USER_AGENT` probably might be [anyone related to a browser](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/)

Comment: Interesting... I tried to toy around the website using an UserAgent switcher and now I cannot load any pages at all! This site probably has a very strict policy on banning user by their IPs if they appear with any sort of UserAgent that denotes a crawler so you might not be able to load it anymore for a while.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the "Setting a real User-Agent and pretending to be a real browser" story, here is a middleware that I've uploaded on github:

- [`scrapy-fake-useragent`](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent)

It is based on [`fake-useragent` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent) and uses a different random `User-Agent` header for every request based on real-world browser usage statistics.

---

Also, make sure you are not violating any rules or terms of use of the web-site. See also:

- [Web scraping etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette)

Answer (score 2):

If the site clearly does not want to be scraped at all, devising a new workaround is only delaying the inevitable -- they will put in a new rule to prevent your new trick, and you're back to square one.

Talk to the site admin -- unless they prevent scraping just to make life hard for others (as some commercial entities do), they might have a good alternative, such as an API or a (paid?) feed you can subscribe to.